# Unity3D Virtual webcam plugin, streams unity viewport contents to other applications as virtual camera for Mac OS

Tags: unity-game-engine, plugins, web-applications, camera, virtual

I want a plugin which will provide a way for unity3D applications to output the viewport to an external application and use the viewport as a webcamera for such applications. 
eg. I am trying to view the Unity cam output in the chrome browser

Comment: I still find it difficult to implement. If someone has any idea then do share.

Comment: I have used the below link to achieve it in Windows: https://github.com/mrayy/UnityCam

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will Vuforia supports Mac OS for developing Augmented Reality applications by using Unity Tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51480614/will-vuforia-supports-mac-os-for-developing-augmented-reality-applications-by-us)